# Graph of a function in a finite union of boxes.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Let $C$ be the graph of a continuous function $\phi: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be any positive number. Show that $C$ can be placed in a finite union of boxes $B_{i} = [a_i,b_i]\times[c_i,d_i]$ such that $C$ does not contain boundary points of $\bigcup B_i$ and such that $\Sigma$ area($B_i$) $\leq \varepsilon$.

**My attempt:**

I tried to make simple partitions but I really don't know how to make things such that the $\varepsilon$ inequality holds. I think I got the idea with a drawing but I'm not really sure. I have little experience with proofs like that. Anything would be great help.

**Some context:**

This exercise is in order to prove the theorem that says:
Let $f: R \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any bounded function real-valued , defined in the rectangle $R$, and suppose that the set of points where $f$ is discontinuous is formed by a finite union of graphs of continuous functions. Then $f$ is integrable over $R$.

Also, some things might be mistranslated, sorry for that.

UPDATE: Already solved it, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hint: f in compact has a maximum and a minimum

Comment: @vvnitram but how do I confirm that $C$ does not contain boundary points, and also how I can make things such that the $\varepsilon$ inequality holds.